# Pass Multiple ViewControllers through One Container View - Xcode 8, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swift3, xcode8

I simply would like to pass a Viewcontroller through the Container View when a Button is pressed. My navigation is in a container view as well and scrolls horizontally(like a dock) 
Here are 2 pictures to illustrate what I am trying to do.
[image]

[image]

Is this possible with a ContainerView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out!!
I removed the blue Container View and swapped it for a Scroll View
Here's the Code for anyone else who is interested in this. Still working on making toe Container View's height dynamic to the content.

This tutorial helped a lot: [Tutorial](https://kodesnippets.com/container-view-in-ios/)

Main View Controller:

```
var container: ContainerViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    container!.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("first")

}

@IBAction func firstBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = "first"
     container!.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent(vc)

}

@IBAction func secondBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    container!.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("second")
}

@IBAction func thirdBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    container!.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("third")
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "container"{

        container = segue.destination as! ContainerViewController

    }
}
```

Container View(Purple View)

```
open class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
    //Manipulating container views
    fileprivate weak var viewController : UIViewController!
    //Keeping track of containerViews
    fileprivate var containerViewObjects = Dictionary<String,UIViewController>()

    /** Specifies which ever container view is on the front */
    open var currentViewController : UIViewController{
        get {
            return self.viewController  
        }
    }

    fileprivate var segueIdentifier : String!

    /*Identifier For First Container SubView*/
    @IBInspectable internal var firstLinkedSubView : String!

    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let identifier = firstLinkedSubView{
            segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent(identifier)
        }
    }

    override open func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent(_ identifier: String) {        
        self.segueIdentifier = identifier
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.segueIdentifier, sender: nil)    
    }

    override open func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == segueIdentifier {            
            //Remove Container View
            if viewController != nil {
                viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
                viewController = nil
            }
            //Add to dictionary if isn't already there
            if ((self.containerViewObjects[self.segueIdentifier] == nil)) {
                viewController = segue.destination
                self.containerViewObjects[self.segueIdentifier] = viewController                
            } else {
                for (key, value) in self.containerViewObjects {
                    if key == self.segueIdentifier {                        
                        viewController = value
                    }
                }
            }

            self.addChildViewController(viewController)
            viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width,height: self.view.frame.height)
            self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
            viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
    }
}
```